# Rebuilding app.config in visual studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

My app.config was giving me several messages related to "usersettings schema not found", so I deleted it with the intention of building it from scratch, but I was not successful. How can I build a new one based on my settings file? Whenever I make a new one and build the solution, it doesn't build the app config file. I don't know what else to try.

Here's the troublesome part of my old file:

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
</startup>
<userSettings>
    <DelocksNote.Settings1>
        <setting name="Font" serializeAs="String">
            <value>DejaVu Sans, 20.25pt, style=Italic</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="WordWrap" serializeAs="String">
            <value>False</value>
        </setting>
    </DelocksNote.Settings1>
</userSettings>
```

Comment: did you check your project properties > Settings?

Comment: Did you check if your app.config file contains an xmlns attribute on any elements? I have seen that getting added by some tools but Visual Studio doesn't like namespaces in .config files.

Comment: Yes, i added the settings again and i keep getting the initial errors: "Message 4 Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'."   and 9 more of those

Comment: Nothing is working omg

Answer (score 75):

Delete the `app.config` file in your solution explorer. Right click the project and select add, add new item. Find "Application Configuration File" in the list and add it. It will be empty.

To generate the contents based on your settings (which should still be intact): edit a setting (make a space or something) and save. Then go look at your new `app.config` file. It will be re-built!

Comment: Don't forget to update service references (right click service under service references project folder and click update service references)

Comment: No need to add. Just deleting the file is enough. After a rebuild, the file will be recreated.

Comment: I had a assembly reference with some build numbers, i removed that whole part of assembly reference and then i recompiled and it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 3):

In Package Manager Console, run this:

```
Get-Project –All | Add-BindingRedirect
```

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/nov/29/updating-assembly-redirects-with-nuget

Comment: When using that command, I found it to be a little more involved than that. I actually answered a question a while back and suggested how to use it, complete with steps, if you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56102381/729541