# c# properties/settings not defined after changing project name and namespace

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, projects-and-solutions

I am updating an old application built several years ago and the global namespace and, project.cs file, and the main form were all named as `email2case_winForm`

I wanted to change this (alongside rebuilding the application in more of an OOP way to make it more flexible, and to be able to re-use code), so changed the names to `email2case`

But now I am having trouble compiling because when reading the settings and properties of the project, those members cannot be found.

Here is an example of the code I am trying to use to read the properties.Settings:

```
XElement x = XElement.Load(email2case.Properties.Settings.Default.e2cConfigFile);
```

and the compiler error for that one is:

> 'email2case.email2case' does not contain a definition for 'Properties'

Here is how a class is reading from the global settings:

```
this.Url = global::email2case.Settings.Default.email2case_sforce_SforceService;
```

and the compiler error for that one is:

> The type or namespace name 'Settings' does not exist in the namespace 'email2case' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have a hunch that the problem is caused by the definitions in `app.Config` and here it is:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <section name="email2case.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
            <section name="email2case.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
        </sectionGroup>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="email2case.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
      <email2case.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="email2case_sforce_SforceService" serializeAs="String">
          <value>https://login.salesforce.com/servi...</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="e2cConfigFile" serializeAs="String">
          <value>C:\email2case\data\e2cConfig.xml</value>
        </setting>
      </email2case.Properties.Settings>
      <email2case.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="email2case_sforce_SforceService" serializeAs="String">
          <value>https://login.salesforce.com/serv...</value>
        </setting>
      </email2case.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings/>
        <client/>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup><userSettings>
        <email2case.email2case.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="enableEWSTrace" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="attachmentsPathLocal" serializeAs="String">
                <value>C:\email2case\temp\</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="eTracePath" serializeAs="String">
                <value>C:\email2case\Trace\</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ewsTraceKeepDays" serializeAs="String">
                <value>1</value>
            </setting>
        </email2case.email2case.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

I don't want to go editing that without knowing exactly the right way to do it, so what code should I use to reference my properties and settings?

Or should I alter the way they are defined in the **app.config**?

Comment: do you see a .settings file in the project.What do you see when you goto Project -> Properties -> Settings  in visual studio ?

Comment: @gideon: Turns out that after correctly changing the global namespace, saving, rebuilding, the correct reference for the properties is `Properties.` and NOT `email2case.Properties.` ... do you think I should add my own answer, or close/delete the question?

Comment: You should answer your question, add detail and accept the answer (the system will allow that after two days)

Comment: @gideon: Thanks I have added it, please would you take a look and see if it makes sense and would be helpful to others?

Comment: Yep it is :) Great job!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue was caused by 2 problems:

1. When you change the namespace, it needs to be done in the Application **Settings** instead of just going into the code and replacing `old namespace` with `new namespace`
2. After incorrectly changing the namespace in the code, the namespace in the code was out of sync with the application settings, and **app.config**

The solution was to

1. Change the namespace in the proper place (in the Project Properties > Application > default Namespace
2. Clean, Rebuild, Save the project

   - If necessary, rebuild the the app.config file following the instructions in this SO post : [Rebuilding app.config in visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399216/rebuilding-app-config-in-visual-studio)
3. Refernce the settings and properties in code using the correct code.

   - in my case this was `Properties.` and NOT `email2case.Properties.` ...

Answer (score 0):

Place cursor in the place (namespace,method) which you want to change and then press F2 then a new window will open and just follow the instructions

renaming the methods or namespace manually will bring more errors because the project was already built so when we run a project visual studio automatically generated the designer code and change need to be done that file too

Comment: This is a helpful tip, but please would you take some time to add some more information about how it would solve the problem, and what the problem was - then I can up-vote it. Being one sentence it should really be just a comment

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem (after changing the casing of the namespace), and read this:
https://stackoverrun.com/de/q/244400

In my case the problem was that `%LocalAppData%\<old namespace>` existed in the old casing and, even during development, the setting were read from that location. I removed the directory and everything returned to working order.